# oracle query : Same filter condition on different column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Im working on the query to improve the performance.

i see query having same filter condition on different column. just think what is the better way of writing the query.

```
select *
from table 1 
where 
col1 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col2 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col3 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col4 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col5 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col6 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col7 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
or 
col8 in (select filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
....... Same condition till col15
```

i tried replacing filtertable using WITH CLAUSE but not much help

```
with filter_temp
(select /*+ materialize  */ filter_value from filtertable where id=1)
select *from table 1 , filter_temp
where col1 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col2 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col3 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col4 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col5 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col6 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col7 in (filtertable.filter_value)
or 
col8 in (filtertable.filter_value)
....... Same condition till col15
```

is there any different way of writing this query.

Comment: Probably no way to fix the query.  You can fix the data model, so you don't have 15 columns containing an "array" of values.  Instead, you want a junction/association table with one row per value.

Comment: What is the current performance of your query and what improvements might you expect?  I’ll second the opinion that based on what I see, you probably can’t.  Your table / data model may prohibit it.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way of writing the query uses `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from filtertable ft
              where ft.id = 1 and
                    ft.filter_value in (t1.col1, t1.col2, . . ., t1.col15)
             );
```

The performance should be pretty similar to your longer version, but this is at least more concise.  I consider that "better" in a way.

The real solution is to have a junction table, so you don't have the column values in a single column on multiple rows rather than stored across different columns in one row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff. i was assuming that if i use WITH CLAUSE, it eliminate  multiple reading of Filtertable but it did't help.